# What is meant by dark matter being non-relativistic and why is this?

Tags: special-relativity, cosmology, dark-matter

What does it mean by dark matter being non-relativistic and why is it non-relativistic?

Answer (score 2):

[Relativistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_relativity) and non relativistic are descriptions of particles, on how close their velocity is to the velocity of light. In various models for [dark matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter) different particles are assumed and different initial cosmic conditions which allow describing the hypothetical particles composing dark matter as relativistic and non relativistic.

In general particles created at the time of Big Bang are at [non relativistic velocities at present](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2020/01/200115140512.htm) .

Comment: okay thank you sm